# is there a gcc alternative to icc's -ax flag

Tags: gcc, compiler-optimization, avx, icc, auto-vectorization

I know icc/icpc can compile and optimize for multiple architectures using the -ax flag (ex -axsavx,sse2 compiles for both avx and sse2 extensions)

Is there something similar to that with gcc/g++?

Comment: Not that I know of; I think GCC's function-multiversioning has to be used manually.

Comment: @PeterCordes how so??

Comment: By using `__attribute__((target("avx2")))` and so on, on certain functions that are worth doing this for and run long enough to be worth adding dynamic dispatch overhead.  e.g. [Will it be feasible to use gcc's function multi-versioning without code changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48882796)  .  Actually that looks like a duplicate of your question.